# Add attribute value to products

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, dropdown-attribute, attribute-set

We need to add an attribute with value Yes to a lot of products (250+), but not to all of our products.
Is there a way to fix this automatically, instead of manually add this value to all 250 products?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not possible as you explain it in the question, because you must have some criteria by which to separate the products for which is need update and the others.